# Assigning value to variable after parsing from top command

Tags: bash, awk, terminal, grep

I am creating a script which will monitor CPU usage. I wanted to use the %CPU value of a particular process and then compare it with a upper-bound limit which will be set by the user. But i am facing issue in parsing that particular %CPU value from the TOP command. I am using TOP, GREP and AWK but i am facing issue in parsing. Please suggest some bash commands. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: i have tried CUT and i have read that PERL along with CUT will work and I am currently working on how to use PERL :)

Comment: can you share commands you tried and failed?

Comment: `PID=$(top -n1 | grep -m1 java | perl -pe 's/\e\[?.*?[\@-~] ?//g' | cut -f1 -d' ')` This is used to extract the PID of a java process. I found this online only but i have no idea on the RE used for PERL.

Comment: when I try top -n1 java doesn't return, did you try top | grep -m1 java?

Comment: yes I have tried that and it returns the complete row for that particular java process. But i want to parse only the %CPU value of this process and then assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(top -i -b -n 1 | grep java |tr -s " " | cut -f 10 -d' ')`

This worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

This will print CPU usage of `bash`

```
top -n1 -b | grep bash | awk '{ print $9 }'
```

Additional information is [here](https://ss64.com/bash/top.html):

> -n num
>          Update display num times, then exit.
>
> -b   Run in batch mode; don't accept command-line input.
>          Useful for sending output to another command or to a file.